# How to use setState in a child component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I started learning React recently and I read in their docs that if you want to share a state between component B and C, you need to lift the state to their nearest parent component A.

I started working on something where my component structure looks like this:

Component A

|

Component B

|

|--Component B.child

|

Component C

|

|--Component C.child

In this case, I want both Component B.child and Component C.child to share a state (let's call it [summary, setSummary]) so what I did was lift the state to Component A which is their nearest parent.

This works and I can pass {summary} to both intended Components properly.

My question is, is there any way that I can use {setSummary} inside Component B.child and Component C.child? If so, how?

The examples I see in their docs the {setState} is being used in the parent component itself not in the children components.

I tried passing it as a prop but it didn't work (maybe I didn't do it properly)

This is a summary of my code:

App.jsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Left from "./components/Left";
import Right from "./components/Right";

function App() {
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState("InitialSummary");

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <Left
        summary={summary}
        setSummary={setSummary}
      ></Left>
      <Right
        summary={summary}
      ></Right>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Left.jsx:

```
import Summary from "./Summary";

export default function Left({
  summary,
  setSummary,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="left">
      <Summary
        existingInfo={summary}
        setExistingInfo={setSummary}
      ></Summary>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Summary.jsx

```
export default function Summary({ existingInfo, setExistingInfo }) {
  const setSummaryToHey = () => {
    setExistingInfo("hey");
  };
  return (
    <form action="#" method="post" className="editSummaryBox">
      <label htmlFor="summaryInput">Summary</label>
      <textarea
        id="summaryInput"
        value={existingInfo}
        onClick={setSummaryToHey}
      ></textarea>
      <button type="submit" className="submitButton">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

On clicking the textarea, the value of the textarea doesn't change to "hey"

Comment: It should be fine to pass `setSummary`. Can you post a minimal working example that demonstrates what doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ruakh I just did :)

Comment: I tested your code using https://playcode.io/, and it worked as you desired -- clicking on the textarea changed the text to "hey". So your problem must be in code that you haven't posted here.

Comment: I noticed I wasn't really passing it the setSummary to the child component but to another component (I had some other code and oversimplified it), sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this by passing your setState as a prop to child component .
but I suggest that use context or another state management if you need pass your state in multiple components .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `setSummary` as a prop to the child components just like you pass summary.
But, I usually use [Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) instead of prop drilling whenever I have to pass the state deep in the render tree.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ComponentA() {
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState("Initial");

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentB setSummary={setSummary} />
      <ComponentC setSummary={setSummary} />
      <p>Summary: {summary}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentB({ setSummary }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentBchild setSummary={setSummary} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentBchild({ setSummary }) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSummary("ComponentBchild");
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>ComponentBchild</button>;
}

function ComponentC({ setSummary }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentCchild setSummary={setSummary} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentCchild({ setSummary }) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSummary("ComponentCchild");
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>ComponentCchild</button>;
}

export default ComponentA;
```

If you wanna play with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/heuristic-surf-jfsdkn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C5).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I see that this works in your code but for some reason it doesn't work with mine. (I edited my first post and made an example) where the value of the textarea doesn't change.